# Windows builder look and feel is ignored

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

How do I set the look and feel **non-programmically**? I tried:

- Going to *Window > Preferences > WindowBuilder > Swing > LookAndFeel* and de-selecting all LookAndFeel's except for 'Windows'
- Tried ticking the `Apply choosen LookAndFeel in main() method.` box (even though I dont want to set it in my main, I just want to have it default)
- In the window builder, in the top toolbar on the right, I have 'Windows' selected

Yet every time I run the program, it always looks like the Metal preset. I don't have any code overriding the look and feel in the main method.

Also I know how to set it via code in the main method, that's not what this question is about.

EDIT: there is no code to share, all I'm doing is creating a new JFrame class, going into the Design tab, dragging the JComboBox into the area and running it.

EDIT2: I'm using Windows and it's an app I'm building just for myself to use on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may specify the L&F as a VM argument :

```
-Dswing.defaultlaf=com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel
```

More globally, you may edit the *swing.properties* file of your Java installation

> swing.defaultlaf=com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel

More information here : [How to Set the Look and Feel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html#properties)